# Why flush() not working in for loop? (PHP)

Tags: php, flush

I want use `flush()` function in `for loop` that echo content after each loop
my code is:

```
<?php
if (ob_get_level() == 0) ob_start();
for ($i = 0; $i<10; $i++){
        echo "<br> Line".$i." to show.";
        ob_flush();
        flush();
        sleep(2);
}

echo "<br>Done.";

ob_end_flush();
?>
```

this code works on localhost and another host(**[Demo](http://citymap.x10.mx/index.php)**) but not working on my main host(**[Demo](http://shoma.info/test/1.php)** + [phpinfo page](http://shoma.info/test/phpinfo.php))

how i can solve this? I use chrome

Answer (score 1):

There's a »[varnish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varnish_%28software%29)« proxy in front of your second server. It disturbs the timing of your script. You should generally not rely on timing when returning your response, precisely because there might be a proxyserver in the way. You might want to use some sort of [polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling_%28computer_science%29) or [WebSockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_socket) instead.

```
$ nc shoma.info 80
GET /test/1.php HTTP/1.1
Host: shoma.info
Connection: close

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.28
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 209
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Sat, 22 Mar 2014 19:18:40 GMT
X-Varnish: 972965439
Age: 0
Via: 1.1 varnish <------- this is the problem
Connection: close

<br> Line 0 to show.<br> Line 1 to show.<br> Line 2 to show.<br> Line 3 to show.<br> Line 4 to show.<br> Line 5 to show.<br> Line 6 to show.<br> Line 7 to show.<br> Line 8 to show.<br> Line 9 to show.<br>Done.
```

BTW: My firefox here doesn't even show the »animation« of your first server. So you can't even rely on the browser displaying it.

Comment: Thanks @escitalopram how i can disable it?

Comment: You can't disable it in a PHP script. It is a server configuration or even a network architecture issue. It's probably best to use AJAX or WebSockets instead of trying to fix it this way.

Comment: I add `Header add "disablevcache" "true"` to `.htaccess` but not working. I will try your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Problem in your PHP configuration.

[output_buffering](https://www.php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php) — is a parameter in your PHP configuration file php.ini. It enable output buffering for data.

In your PHP configuration it has '**no value**'. So, just set **output_buffering** parameter '**On**'. Or if you want set some limit for buffering data set count of bytes (for example'4096') in this directive.

Comment: why »On«? Shouldn't buffering _delay_ the sending of the response?

Comment: Did you restart web-server?

Comment: not in host server.but code working fine in localhost with `on` or `off` for `output_buffering`.( i restarted localhost.)

Answer (score 0):

Try set this at the beggining:

```
ini_set('implicit_flush', true);
```

[Source here](http://www.binarytides.com/php-output-content-browser-realtime-buffering/)